# Part of image is not showing when added to AppBar in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-appbar

When I try to add an image to the Appbar in Flutter as like the following:

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
        child: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Image.asset('images/Ataxx.jpg'),
        ),
      )
```

I get the following output:

[image]

As you see part of the image is missing from the top! how to correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rgisi suggests you really don't need to use `PreferredSize()` you just need to pass your image in the title.

```
appBar: AppBar(
    titleSpacing: 0,
    elevation: 0,
    title: Image.network(
      'https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ZFcWRAX7L.png',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
```

And for your use case if you really want to use `PreferredSize()` you can use that like this.

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100),
    child: Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Image.network(
          'https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ZFcWRAX7L.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

You will get something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think there's no need to use a `PreferredSizeWidget` because `AppBar` itself already implements `PreferredSizeWidget`.

Furthermore, I use [`FittedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) to place the image in the app bar - see the example code for how to use it.